# Namecheap DNS Cname issue

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, namecheap

I am using Namecheap default DNS, where I bought the dns name. However, I am having a issue...

Typically, for AWS and Rackspace I would have:

```
A Record: foo.com 124.22.22.1
Cname:    www.example.com foo.com
```

But for Namecheap I have to use `@` to show server root:

```
A Record: @ 124.22.22.1
Cname:    www.example.com example.com
```

With Namecheap DNS, `http://example.com` works but not `www.example.com` with `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did support say when you contacted them about their service?

Comment: they use url redirect

Comment: You might need to add a dot after the TLD (like "www IN CNAME foo.com.")

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: make `www.foo.com` direct to my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the only way to get this done without a URL redirect record is to have 2 A records:

```
A Record: @ 124.22.22.1
A Record: www 124.22.22.1
```

This mostly due to I have to use `@` as the domain name. Because of this, I can not use `cname` record as the input will not allow `@` and namescheap dns does not use domain name, but `@`.

Answer (score 5):

If you were to write `www.example.com` inside a zone file for `example.com.` the actual name you have created is `www.example.com.example.com.`

Instead you can append a `.` to the name to make it absolute rather than relative. In that case you would write `www.example.com.`

Alternatively you could use a relative name and write only `www` without a `.` which since it is relative will become `www.example.com.` once the zone name has been appended.

If you have come across a provider which will allow you to create a record for `www.example.com.` by only writing `www.example.com` it would be because that provider automatically appends the trailing `.` behind the scenes, which can be confusing since not all providers do this.